# Custom implementation of malloc in C++

Tags: c++, c, memory, malloc, free

I came across an interview question where they asked to implement malloc() and free function in C++ .

At the very beginning a char array of size 50000 is declared(50000 bytes). Assuming this is the heap memory, write malloc and free functions to allocate blocks of memory and free up memory.

Any one can provide me with C++ working/pseudo code or just explain the mechanism? (obviously code would make it a lot easier to understand).

Thanks,
Rohit

Comment: I think this is overly broad, an allocator is too large to fit in an answer, and the basics are [readily available on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#Dynamic_memory_allocation) so adding them here has low value.

Comment: I think the idea behind the interview question was to make *you* think about how you would manage your own memory, and how you'd keep track of what's used and what's unused. Make an effort!

Comment: Please be more specific about where you are stuck.

Comment: c++ or c? I would think "custom implementation of malloc in C"

Answer (score 6):

While writing a production-level dynamic memory allocator is a very hard task, writing a toy one is straightforward. The question is obviously meant to test your skills, but it is still fair to look for inspiration in the works of others.

"The C Programming Language" by Kernighan & Ritchie [contains a simple implementation](http://www.julienlecomte.net/simplix/sh.php?f=src/lib/stdlib.c) of `malloc`. Study it and consider the implications of its design and implementation. Consider how you would improve it to perform better, fragment less, or handle multiple threads. After that, it should no longer be hard to write your own toy allocator, and answer any questions that arise.

Answer (score 2):

There are several different algorithms which can be used.  For such a
small memory, I'd just prefix each block with a pointer to the next
block, and a flag indicating whether it is allocated or freed.  An
allocation consists of finding a large enough free block, splitting it
if necessary, and marking the returned block as allocated.  A free
consists of marking the block as free.  At some point, you also have to
coalesce blocks: if two free blocks follow each other, they are merged
into one.  (I did this during allocation in my implementation.)

The above algorithm isn't very difficult in itself.  The real trick is
getting all of the different casts and such right.  It's a good exercise
in very low level programming.

Answer (score -4):

I have not tested it before , but i think it is possible to do this by using new keyword and templates to support generic state for creating array of desired types , 
but i will follow this question to find out the response of C++ heroes .

Comment: I think using `new` isn't the solution for this.

Comment: create malloc using new?